# How to create a folder with the job number in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to create a folder inside the D:\Contracts\${JobNumber of the job} while running the code in jenkins. is it possible?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins have a directory plugin

```
fileOperations([folderCreateOperation('directoryname')])
```

this can help you to create a directory and the build number you can pass as an variable "directoryname" as

```
${env.BUILD_NUMBER} //will give you build number.
```

Alternatively you can use shell script inside a build job to do the same operation.